# Use of Variables in Block Method of Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby program and I found the following while working on Arrays and Files

```
nums = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2; }
puts nums

File.foreach("users.txt") { |line| puts line }
```

The program works well.  However, I didn't know what is meant by `|e|` or `|line|` in the blocks

Kindly explain me the use of the variables in blocks

Comment: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/blocks/arguments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Viktor mentioned they are block arguments. `e` represents an index of an item of an [array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html) in each iteration, `line` each line when you are iterating through the lines of a file.
Here is the pseudocode:

```
nums = Array.new(10) # Returns an array of size 10 filled up with nil values
for(i = 0; i < nums.length(); i++) {
  e = i * 2 # This is `e` variable in the block
  nums[i] = e
}


file_lines = File.readlines("users.txt") 
for(i = 0; i < file_lines.length(); i++) {
  line = file_lines[i] # This is `line` variable in the block
  print(line)
}
```

By the way, in the first example, the assignment is unnecessary because after each iteration a block returns the last evaluated value, so you can rewrite it like this `nums = Array.new(10) { |e| e * 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

> However, I didn't know what is meant by `|e|` or `|line|` in the blocks

This is called a *parameter list*. A *parameter* is like a "hole" in a subroutine (in this case a *block*, but methods can also have parameters and thus a parameter list) that can be filled in later. The thing that is being used to fill in the hole is called an *argument*. Arguments are being passed in an *argument list*.

So, in this case you have a *parameter list* with one parameter called `e`, or `line`, respectively.

Note that the assignment in the first snippet is useless. There is no code after the assignment which uses the parameter again, so it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

`{ ... }` defines a  block and `|...|` holds the block's argument(s). Block arguments are similar to method arguments.

You can use `do ... end` instead of `{ ... }` and split the code to multiple lines:

```
File.foreach("users.txt") do |line|
  puts line
end
```

---

`Array.new(10) { ... }` creates a 10-element array. For each element, the block is called and the element's (zero-based) index is passed to the block. This is what `e` is in your example. You can choose the variable name yourself. (`e` for element, `i` for index, or `n` for number are typical variable names)

The block's return value then defines the element's value. Some examples:

```
Array.new(10) { |i| 5 }      # not using the index at all
#=> [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

Array.new(10) { |i| i }      # returning the unchanged index
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Array.new(10) { |i| 10 - i }  # subtracting the index from 10
#=> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Array.new(10) { |i| i * i }  # multiplying the index by itself
#=> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

As you can see, the index can be used to create a variety of sequences.

Also note that the assignment (`e =`) in your example is superfluous. Only the block's return value matters.

---

`File.foreach` passes the lines of a file to the given block while reading the file, one after another. Within the block, you can decide what to do with that line. In your example, you `puts` it. Unlike `Array.new` above, `File.foreach` doesn't use the block's return value afterwards.

---

In general, many Ruby methods accept blocks. It allows the method to pass values to the block for further processing. Some methods use the blocks return value, others don't.

Comment: Thanks to all and now I understood the concept